# Importing Sample data for wordpress theme gives error : Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in import.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When i import the sample data for wordpress, I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /var/www/../wp-content/plugins/theme-addons/includes/import.php:605

the code at this line is:

```
    $import_data = $parser->parse( $file );
if ( isset( $import_data['posts'] ) ) { // this is line 605
    $posts = $import_data['posts'];

    if ( $posts && sizeof( $posts ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            if ( 'product' === $post['post_type'] ) {
                if ( ! empty( $post['terms'] ) ) {
                    foreach ( $post['terms'] as $term ) {
                        if ( strstr( $term['domain'], 'pa_' ) ) {
                            if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $term['domain'] ) ) {
                                $attribute_name = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( str_replace( 'pa_', '', $term['domain'] ) );

                                // Create the taxonomy
                                if ( ! in_array( $attribute_name, wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() ) ) {
                                    $attribute = array(
                                        'attribute_label'   => $attribute_name,
                                        'attribute_name'    => $attribute_name,
                                        'attribute_type'    => 'select',
                                        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order',
                                        'attribute_public'  => 0
                                    );
                                    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );
                                    delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
                                }

                                // Register the taxonomy now so that the import works!
                                register_taxonomy(
                                    $term['domain'],
                                    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_' . $term['domain'], array( 'product' ) ),
                                    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_args_' . $term['domain'], array(
                                        'hierarchical' => true,
                                        'show_ui'      => false,
                                        'query_var'    => true,
                                        'rewrite'      => false,
                                    ) )
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it again? Maybe just a temporary error. There seems to be something wrong with the products you are importing. Is there a custom post type "product" in your installation? It should be if "Woocommerce" is installed. If not, please install woocommerce to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot of times. I have woocommerce installed as it is woocommerce store template. I had a similar issue with other theme as well while importing sample data. I Got this error - Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www//wp-content/plugins/soo-demo-importer/soo-demo-importer.php:278, both time it is related to zip file imprting. I am using a vps, so i also installed php zip but still getting this error.